# Writing A Microsoft Fastcall 64-Bit Assembly Function

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, calling-convention

I am having some issues with writing a 64-Bit fastcall function trough shellcode, and the issue is that it seems to mess with other functions being called before and after it and despite working, after a couple of times the parameter I pass ends up becoming junk for some reason and not being what I passed to it which makes me think I may be misinterpreting how this calling convention works.

For example, I call printf before the call to print 2 of the parameters I use, and this is what happens to them after the first run:

```
  printf("RAX: %p\nR10: %p\n\n",mem2,mem);
  function((U64)mem2,(U64)mem,1);
```

Output:

```
RAX: 0000000000597D00
R10: 0000000000597B80

RAX: 0000000000190000
R10: 0000000000597D00
```

*The second value of RAX is actually the address at which the shellcode is allocated and I have no idea how it ended up there.

P.S. I wrote the same function in 32-Bit with the stdcall calling convention and it works perfectly, so the main part of it, which stayed the same with the exception of the registers used, works properly.

So the documentation specifies the first 3 parameters will be put into RCX, RDX and R8, respecively and that RAX, R10, R11, etc. are to be used inside the function, so that is where I store the parameters to be used (They are modified troughout the duration of the function).

Here is the function prototype:

```
typedef void(__fastcall*f_proto)(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c);
```

Here is how it looks like:

```
PUSH RBP
MOV RBP, RSP
MOV RAX, RCX
MOV R10, RDX
MOV R11, R8
...
MOV RSP, RBP
POP RBP
RETN 0x18
```

Comment: 64 bit convention is caller cleanup you don't want the `RETN 0x18` just use `RETN`. Also make sure you set up the shadow space properly (not shown).

Comment: Wikipedia has it listed as Calee cleanup, so I guess they messed up there. Indeed not cleaning it up myself fixed my issue. Also, is there some need to set up the shadow space if I'm not using any local variables or stack parameters?

Comment: You need the shadow space if you call another function. It was not clear whether you do that in the omitted code or not.

Comment: If not using RBP, there is no need to save it.

Answer (score 1):

64 bit windows only uses one calling convention, called the 'Microsoft x64 calling convention' (well two if you include `__vectorcall`). Wikipedia talks about 32 bit calling conventions separately and then talks about the single 64 bit microsoft calling convention. I have a diagram of that calling convention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/61157110/7194773). The [MDSN page for the calling conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=msvc-160) is talking about the x86 calling conventions and then it directs you to a link if you are looking for the x64 calling convention, and you need to be aware of the home space and `rsp` alignment after the call.

On the Wikipedia page:

> Microsoft `__fastcall` convention (aka `__msfastcall`) passes the first two arguments (evaluated left to right) that fit into ECX and EDX. Remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack from right to left. When the compiler compiles for IA64 or AMD64, it ignores the `__fastcall` keyword and uses the one 64-bit calling convention instead.

On the `__stdcall` MSDN page:

> On ARM and x64 processors, `__stdcall` is accepted and ignored by the compiler

On the `__cdecl` MSDN page:

> On ARM and x64 processors, `__cdecl` is accepted but typically ignored by the compiler. By convention on ARM and x64, arguments are passed in registers when possible, and subsequent arguments are passed on the stack. In x64 code, use `__cdecl` to override the /Gv compiler option and use the default x64 calling convention.

Only `__vectorcall` does something different on x64

Comment: MS describes their standard x64 calling convention as [a four-register fast-call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160), presumably because it's somewhat similar to 32-bit `fastcall`, using the same 2 regs as the first 2 of 4 arg-passing regs.  (But is otherwise different: caller-pops, and with shadow space).  And on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-160, they literally call it `__fastcall`.  (The compiler can ignore that keyword, since as you say `__vectorcall` is the only non-default convention.)